# URLs in comments not being parsed correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, hyperlinks

I'm seeing a number of links for URL's in comments being truncated early, e.g;

[image]

... on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38927239/mips-program-to-find-the-sum-and-square-sum-of-10-integers#comment65215224_38927239.

Notice how it is truncated early. I have seen this in multiple other comments as well. I have tried disabling extensions etc. to no avail. This is on Chrome 52.

Comment: For example; http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283408/domain-names-followed-by-full-stops-create-invalid-idn-domain-names, probably.

Comment: Cross-site dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283480/link-length-format-in-comments

Comment: ^ oh the irony.. at least the truncated part is not important

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/24836/mathjax-is-breaking-in-short-expressions-frequently-today

Is this a related bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed, this was due to a "fix" for a different problem. Regexes are hard. Dammit.

Fix going out now.

Comment: It's still (or: again) buggy :D http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335868/bug-in-auto-url-parsing-in-comments

Comment: @DanFromGermany that is "by design" in the sense that we cannot really distinguish a `&quote;` from a URL parameter followed by a semicolon.