# Bug in Auto URL parsing in comments

Tags: bug, comments

Putting this in the comments:

```
text "http://evil.com" text
```

Outputs this when sent:

> text "[evil.com"](http://evil.com); text

Notice the last single quote is beeing added to the link and a `;` is added.

This is the rendered HTML:

```
text "<a href="http://evil.com&quot;" rel="nofollow">evil.com"</a>; text
```

Feel free to try in the comments below.

Comment: example "http://example.com" example

Comment: Raised [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112114/urls-wrapped-in-are-not-parsing-correctly-in-comments) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56605/recognize-urls-in-angle-brackets-in-comments) - though the second one involves brackets rather than quotes